# What could cause a draft of the current email to be saved in mu4e?

Tags: mu4e, email

I have a strange issue I can not quite nail down to a cause. *Only* sometimes when I am writing an email or responding to one, a draft of it gets saved. I thought this maybe due to the fact that my Emacs temporary file backup directory was not set properly hence the backups were being stored somewhere in my mail directory; getting synced. This issue is mentioned [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/21723/25462).

I checked by creating a new file and confirming that while it has unsaved changes, its backups are indeed stored in the directory I set up. Then to narrow down why the drafts of my emails were getting saved I typed up a new email and tried to do the same by opening the compose buffer by replying to one, typing changes and leaving but this time no drafts were saved.

Drafts do every now and then get saved and I can't seem to figure out when that happens and how can I keep that from happening or delete them once that particular email is sent (which currently does not happen).

Also, say when I am typing an email and I save it manually which saves a draft, and then finish the email and send it, that draft also does not get deleted.

1. I want to figure out when and why the automatic drafts are saved, and possibly not save them.
2. Once an email is sent, I want the draft saved for it to be deleted and that email to only exist in the sent folder.

My `mu4e-sent-messages-behavior` is set to `delete`.